# qFastSin and qFastCos (Speed, safety and precision)

Tags: c++, api, qt, math

Recently I found two mathematical functions in `qmath.h` named `qFastSin` and `qFastCos`. These functions are `inline` and uses look-up tables to calculate the value of sin and cos:

```
inline qreal qFastSin(qreal x)
{
    // Calculating si would be more accurate with qRound, but slower.
    int si = int(x * (0.5 * QT_SINE_TABLE_SIZE / M_PI)); 
    qreal d = x - si * (2.0 * M_PI / QT_SINE_TABLE_SIZE);
    int ci = si + QT_SINE_TABLE_SIZE / 4;
    si &= QT_SINE_TABLE_SIZE - 1;
    ci &= QT_SINE_TABLE_SIZE - 1;
    return qt_sine_table[si] + (qt_sine_table[ci] - 0.5 * qt_sine_table[si] * d) * d;
}

inline qreal qFastCos(qreal x)
{
    // Calculating ci would be more accurate with qRound, but slower.
    int ci = int(x * (0.5 * QT_SINE_TABLE_SIZE / M_PI)); 
    qreal d = x - ci * (2.0 * M_PI / QT_SINE_TABLE_SIZE);
    int si = ci + QT_SINE_TABLE_SIZE / 4;
    si &= QT_SINE_TABLE_SIZE - 1;
    ci &= QT_SINE_TABLE_SIZE - 1;
    return qt_sine_table[si] - (qt_sine_table[ci] + 0.5 * qt_sine_table[si] * d) * d;
}
```

I searched Google and Qt-Assistant for information about them, but there is no good documentaion.

**Does anybody know about precision and performance of these function? *(Specially precision)***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are not part of the public API, not supported, not documented, and subject to change.

Qt only documents what it supports and it [only supports what it documents](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtcore-qmath-h.html). It's good like that.

It looks like a simple linear interpolation so accuracy depends on `QT_SINE_TABLE_SIZE` and also how close to a sample point the input happens to be. The worse case error will then be `1-sin(pi/2 + 2*pi*(QT_SINE_TABLE_SIZE/2))`

If you care about performance more than accuracy then you can use them in practice but in theory *they may be removed entirely* in future.

Comment: It uses the quadratic Taylor polynomials centered on the sample points of the table, not interpolation. For `x=xi+d` it returns `sin(x) ~ sin(xi)+cos(xi)*d-0.5*sin(xi)*d*d` and `cos(x) ~ cos(xi)-sin(xi)*d-0.5*cos(xi)*d*d`.

Answer (score 1):

I tested using random values and millions of iterations and the maximum error that I got was ~0.00000246408 compared to std::sin/cos. It also seems to be ~5x faster.