# What is the most efficient general sin(x) algorithm, and how efficient is it?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, trigonometry

Using some series work messing with factorials, I discovered a connection between a polynomial expansion of a factorial and a polynomial expansion of a sin that were very similar.

After creating a small program to generate coefficients of the factorial's polynomial expansion (it's actually really pointless here as it requires calculation of factorial in order to generate a factorial's :P), I was able to add a multiplication by Pi and create an O(n^2) algorithm for sin(x). I wanted to compare it to other algorithms for calculating for sin.

I looked online, but I couldn't find much about sin calculations. I found CORDIC, but couldn't find anything about efficient implementations, so eventually I gave up and came to ask here as it's a good question for anyone interested in the calculations of trigonometric functions in computers.

So what's the typical and/or best way to find sin(x) in software and how does my algorithm stand up?

Comment: Have you checked these [software implementations of CORDIC](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/cordic/cordic.html)?

Comment: I am not sure what `n` you are referring to in your question, but if it is the number of bits precision, then see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19946/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-computing-sinx-to-t-bits-of-precision. Practically I think implementations are never actually concerned with achieving guaranteed precision and they would be limited by the floating point precision anyway, so I am not sure what you mean with `O(n^2)` here.

Answer (score 4):

The best way of Googling this is to figure out how it's done by some popular language, such as by searching for `std::sin implementation`, which would give you the C++ implementation.

What follows is one of the implementations used by the GCC standard mathematical library (drawn from [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c;hb=HEAD#l281)).

```
/*******************************************************************/
/* An ultimate sin routine. Given an IEEE double machine number x   */
/* it computes the correctly rounded (to nearest) value of sin(x)  */
/*******************************************************************/
#ifndef IN_SINCOS
double
SECTION
__sin (double x)
{
 double t, a, da;
 mynumber u;
 int4 k, m, n;
 double retval = 0;

 SET_RESTORE_ROUND_53BIT (FE_TONEAREST);

 u.x = x;
 m = u.i[HIGH_HALF];
 k = 0x7fffffff & m;           /* no sign           */
 if (k < 0x3e500000)           /* if x->0 =>sin(x)=x */
   {
     math_check_force_underflow (x);
     retval = x;
   }
/*--------------------------- 2^-26<|x|< 0.855469---------------------- */
 else if (k < 0x3feb6000)
   {
     /* Max ULP is 0.548.  */
     retval = do_sin (x, 0);
   }                           /*   else  if (k < 0x3feb6000)    */

/*----------------------- 0.855469  <|x|<2.426265  ----------------------*/
 else if (k < 0x400368fd)
   {
     t = hp0 - fabs (x);
     /* Max ULP is 0.51.  */
     retval = copysign (do_cos (t, hp1), x);
   }                           /*   else  if (k < 0x400368fd)    */

/*-------------------------- 2.426265<|x|< 105414350 ----------------------*/
 else if (k < 0x419921FB)
   {
     n = reduce_sincos (x, &a, &da);
     retval = do_sincos (a, da, n);
   }                           /*   else  if (k <  0x419921FB )    */

/* --------------------105414350 <|x| <2^1024------------------------------*/
 else if (k < 0x7ff00000)
   {
     n = __branred (x, &a, &da);
     retval = do_sincos (a, da, n);
   }
/*--------------------- |x| > 2^1024 ----------------------------------*/
 else
   {
     if (k == 0x7ff00000 && u.i[LOW_HALF] == 0)
       __set_errno (EDOM);
     retval = x / x;
   }

 return retval;
}
```

this calls

```
 /* Given a number partitioned into X and DX, this function computes the sine of
    the number by combining the sin and cos of X (as computed by a variation of
    the Taylor series) with the values looked up from the sin/cos table to get
    the result.  */
 static inline double
 __always_inline
 do_sin (double x, double dx)
 {
   double xold = x;
   /* Max ULP is 0.501 if |x| < 0.126, otherwise ULP is 0.518.  */
   if (fabs (x) < 0.126)
     return TAYLOR_SIN (x * x, x, dx);

   mynumber u;

   if (x <= 0)
     dx = -dx;
   u.x = big + fabs (x);
   x = fabs (x) - (u.x - big);

   double xx, s, sn, ssn, c, cs, ccs, cor;
   xx = x * x;
   s = x + (dx + x * xx * (sn3 + xx * sn5));
   c = x * dx + xx * (cs2 + xx * (cs4 + xx * cs6));
   SINCOS_TABLE_LOOKUP (u, sn, ssn, cs, ccs);
   cor = (ssn + s * ccs - sn * c) + cs * s;
   return copysign (sn + cor, xold);
 }
```

and

```
/* Given a number partitioned into X and DX, this function computes the cosine
  of the number by combining the sin and cos of X (as computed by a variation
  of the Taylor series) with the values looked up from the sin/cos table to
  get the result.  */
static inline double
__always_inline
do_cos (double x, double dx)
{
 mynumber u;

 if (x < 0)
   dx = -dx;

 u.x = big + fabs (x);
 x = fabs (x) - (u.x - big) + dx;

 double xx, s, sn, ssn, c, cs, ccs, cor;
 xx = x * x;
 s = x + x * xx * (sn3 + xx * sn5);
 c = xx * (cs2 + xx * (cs4 + xx * cs6));
 SINCOS_TABLE_LOOKUP (u, sn, ssn, cs, ccs);
 cor = (ccs - s * ssn - cs * c) - sn * s;
 return cs + cor;
}
```

as

```
#define SINCOS_TABLE_LOOKUP(u, sn, ssn, cs, ccs) \
({                                                                            \
 int4 k = u.i[LOW_HALF] << 2;                                                \
 sn = __sincostab.x[k];                                                      \
 ssn = __sincostab.x[k + 1];                                                 \
 cs = __sincostab.x[k + 2];                                                  \
 ccs = __sincostab.x[k + 3];                                                 \
})
```

So the answer to your question is that a smart implementation combines Taylor series expansions with table look-ups.

Here's another such approach, used by [Sun](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/k_sin.c):

```
/* @(#)k_sin.c 1.3 95/01/18 */
/*
 * ====================================================
 * Copyright (C) 1993 by Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Developed at SunSoft, a Sun Microsystems, Inc. business.
 * Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this
 * software is freely granted, provided that this notice 
 * is preserved.
 * ====================================================
 */

/* __kernel_sin( x, y, iy)
 * kernel sin function on [-pi/4, pi/4], pi/4 ~ 0.7854
 * Input x is assumed to be bounded by ~pi/4 in magnitude.
 * Input y is the tail of x.
 * Input iy indicates whether y is 0. (if iy=0, y assume to be 0). 
 *
 * Algorithm
 *  1. Since sin(-x) = -sin(x), we need only to consider positive x. 
 *  2. if x < 2^-27 (hx<0x3e400000 0), return x with inexact if x!=0.
 *  3. sin(x) is approximated by a polynomial of degree 13 on
 *     [0,pi/4]
 *                 3            13
 *      sin(x) ~ x + S1*x + ... + S6*x
 *     where
 *  
 *  |sin(x)         2     4     6     8     10     12  |     -58
 *  |----- - (1+S1*x +S2*x +S3*x +S4*x +S5*x  +S6*x   )| <= 2
 *  |  x                     | 
 * 
 *  4. sin(x+y) = sin(x) + sin'(x')*y
 *        ~ sin(x) + (1-x*x/2)*y
 *     For better accuracy, let 
 *         3      2      2      2      2
 *    r = x *(S2+x *(S3+x *(S4+x *(S5+x *S6))))
 *     then                   3    2
 *    sin(x) = x + (S1*x + (x *(r-y/2)+y))
 */

#include "fdlibm.h"

#ifdef __STDC__
static const double 
#else
static double 
#endif
half =  5.00000000000000000000e-01, /* 0x3FE00000, 0x00000000 */
S1  = -1.66666666666666324348e-01, /* 0xBFC55555, 0x55555549 */
S2  =  8.33333333332248946124e-03, /* 0x3F811111, 0x1110F8A6 */
S3  = -1.98412698298579493134e-04, /* 0xBF2A01A0, 0x19C161D5 */
S4  =  2.75573137070700676789e-06, /* 0x3EC71DE3, 0x57B1FE7D */
S5  = -2.50507602534068634195e-08, /* 0xBE5AE5E6, 0x8A2B9CEB */
S6  =  1.58969099521155010221e-10; /* 0x3DE5D93A, 0x5ACFD57C */

#ifdef __STDC__
  double __kernel_sin(double x, double y, int iy)
#else
  double __kernel_sin(x, y, iy)
  double x,y; int iy;   /* iy=0 if y is zero */
#endif
{
  double z,r,v;
  int ix;
  ix = __HI(x)&0x7fffffff;  /* high word of x */
  if(ix<0x3e400000)     /* |x| < 2**-27 */
     {if((int)x==0) return x;}    /* generate inexact */
  z =  x*x;
  v =  z*x;
  r =  S2+z*(S3+z*(S4+z*(S5+z*S6)));
  if(iy==0) return x+v*(S1+z*r);
  else      return x-((z*(half*y-v*r)-y)-v*S1);
}
```

Other methods include using assembly instructions so that the calculation is done in hardware (though this has occasionally led to [problems](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/)).

More information is available at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284860/how-does-c-compute-sin-and-other-math-functions) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662261/fastest-implementation-of-sine-cosine-and-square-root-in-c-doesnt-need-to-b/37947583).