# vectorizing branched table lookup in SSE fast approximate cosine

Tags: c, assembly, x86, vectorization, sse

I'm making a small game engine for personal use. The target architecture is x86_64 preferably with SSE2.

The sine/cosine function is one of the core parts, and it's implemented as a precomputed table of 1024 cosine values for the input range `[0, π / 2]`.

The scalar implementation is quite straightforward.

```
typedef unsigned uns;
typedef float flt;

enum {COS_TABLE_SIZE = 1 << 10};
extern flt COS_TABLE[COS_TABLE_SIZE];

flt f(uns i) {
    flt *t = COS_TABLE;
    uns z = COS_TABLE_SIZE;
    switch (i / z) {
    case 0:
        return +t[+(i - z * 0) + 0];
    case 1:
        return -t[-(i - z * 1) + z];
    case 2:
        return -t[+(i - z * 2) + 0];
    case 3:
        return +t[-(i - z * 3) + z];
    default:
        __builtin_unreachable();
    }
}
```

The code isn't tested yet, so there could be an error in math.

Modern compilers aren't sophisticated enough to generate good code for the naivest approach to vectorization.

```
typedef uns u32;
typedef u32 vec_u32 __attribute__((vector_size(16)));
typedef flt vec_flt __attribute__((vector_size(16)));

vec_flt fv(vec_u32 i) {
    vec_flt r;
    for (uns j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        r[j] = f(i[j]);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Both GCC and Clang produce horrible code for `fv`. So I decided to do the vectorization manually.

When you have a look below, the code above `/*---*/` isn't related much to this question. The branching in the scalar version is converted to a branchless vectorized version. Please do comment if there is room for improvement in that part.

Anyway, this question is about the lines below `/*---*/`. The given problem is to create a vector from a vector of indices by doing table look-ups with those indices. In C, the upper part looks more complex, but in machine level the lower part is more expensive. Extracting each index value separately from a vector and then reconstructing a vector with the results doesn't seem to be a simple task.

What is an efficient way to deal with such problem? It is a personal project, and any kind of restructuring is always possible.

I prefer SSE2 for portability, but if there is a better solution available in later extensions, it would be good to know.

```
static uns uns_log2(uns x) {
    if (__builtin_constant_p(x)) {
        return 31 - __builtin_clz(x);
    }
    uns r = 0;
    __asm__ ("bsr\t%0, %1" : "+r"(r) : "r"(x));
    return r;
}

static u32 flt_reint_u32(flt x) {
    u32 r;
    memcpy(&r, &x, sizeof(x));
    return r;
}

static flt u32_reint_flt(u32 x) {
    flt r;
    memcpy(&r, &x, sizeof(x));
    return r;
}

static vec_u32 vec_u32_fill(u32 x) {
    return (vec_u32){x, x, x, x};
}

vec_flt fv2(vec_u32 i) {
    flt *t = COS_TABLE;
    uns z = COS_TABLE_SIZE;
    vec_u32 q = i >> uns_log2(z);
    i -= q << uns_log2(z);
    vec_u32 c = q == 1 | q == 3;
    i = i & ~c | z - i & c;
    vec_u32 s = vec_u32_fill(0x80000000);
    s &= ~(q == 0 | q == 3);
    
    /*---*/
    
    vec_flt r;
    for (uns j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        r[j] = u32_reint_flt(flt_reint_u32(t[i[j]]) ^ s[j]);
    }
    return r;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/aejc69q9Y

Comment: Have you looked at existing vectorized sin/cos library functions, like glibc's libmvec?  (https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/libmvec)  Looks like their [SSE4 version](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch/svml_s_cosf4_core_sse4.S.html) uses a different strategy, though, with a polynomial approximation.  And only falling back to calling scalar cosf for some inputs.  Yours is I guess aiming to be faster and lower-precision?

Comment: Without AVX2 for gather loads, you're definitely going to have to extract to scalar for table lookups.  When you need all 4 elements, probably best to just store to tmp array and scalar reload it, instead of doing movd + 3x pextrd.  Especially with SSE2!  You might still do the first with movd, and the rest as reloads.  The manual gather should be 4x movss + 3 shuffles, or possibly 2x `movss + movhps` pairs to save front-end bandwidth (but still costs a p5 uop in the back end micro-fused with it) and one `shufps`, if cache-line splits don't make 8-byte loads worse.  (Page-align your table)

Comment: XOR is slow, IF-ELSE is slow, get rid of these. Try to use `register` keyword for the the hot variables. Declare the hot variables as high as possible, best in function scope. Jump tables (`goto`) are faster than function calls. Try to write the hot stuff all within one singular function.

Comment: As @PeterCordes said, doing a LUT without AVX2 is not possible in parallel. And you are likely much faster with a polynomial approximation. If you just need 10 bits of precision, 2--4 terms should be sufficient (you can also split the interval in two halves and calculate sine and cosine at the same time).

Comment: @paladin The only thing I can partly agree with of your comment is that branching is (potentially) slow. But on what (modern) architecture is XOR slow, or which compiler needs the `register` keyword to decide what variables are hot? Also, compilers are pretty good at inlining, so no need to write big monolithic functions.

Comment: @paladin: if/else can be slow if done on runtime variables, but `__builtin_constant_p()` is evaluated at compile time.  Integer `^` is one of the cheapest integer operations, and x86 can PXOR on 128 bits at once.  The `register` keyword has literally no effect on performance when optimization is enabled in modern compilers.  Declaring variables earlier also has no effect.   These helper functions will all inline; the only slow thing is the `switch` in the first version.  Have you [looked at optimized asm output from a compiler](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116/224132) in the past 2 decades?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662261/fastest-implementation-of-sine-cosine-and-square-root-in-c-doesnt-need-to-b

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the comments. This is my current solution.

Table look-up with vectors cannot be done efficiently without AVX2. Fortunately, for sine and cosine, Taylor series expansion apparently converges quite fast. With only 4 terms, the maximum absolute error is `0.0000068` and the average absolute error is `0.0000042`.

The coefficients of the polynomial with a certain length can be optimized to minimize the error. The precomputed coefficients are from this website (https://publik-void.github.io/sin-cos-approximations/, Cos, abs. error minimized, degree 6)

This is the whole assembly output for cosine. The input should always be in the range `[-π / 2, π / 2]`.

```
vec_flt_cos:
    andps   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
    movaps  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR .LC2[rip]
    movaps  xmm3, XMMWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
    movaps  xmm2, XMMWORD PTR .LC3[rip]
    subps   xmm1, xmm0
    cmpltps xmm3, xmm0
    pxor    xmm1, xmm0
    pand    xmm1, xmm3
    pxor    xmm1, xmm0
    movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC7[rip]
    mulps   xmm1, xmm1
    pand    xmm0, xmm3
    mulps   xmm2, xmm1
    addps   xmm2, XMMWORD PTR .LC4[rip]
    mulps   xmm2, xmm1
    addps   xmm2, XMMWORD PTR .LC5[rip]
    mulps   xmm1, xmm2
    addps   xmm1, XMMWORD PTR .LC6[rip]
    pxor    xmm0, xmm1
    ret
```

Below is the code for testing the accuracy, if you're interested.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define FLT_PI 3.14159265358979323846f
#define FLT_DPI 6.28318530717958647693f
#define FLT_HPI 1.57079632679489661923f

typedef unsigned uns;
typedef uint32_t u32;
typedef uint64_t u64;
typedef int32_t i32;
typedef float flt;
typedef double dbl;
typedef flt vec_flt __attribute__((vector_size(16)));
typedef u32 vec_u32 __attribute__((vector_size(16)));
typedef i32 vec_i32 __attribute__((vector_size(16)));

static vec_flt vec_flt_fill(flt x) {
    return (vec_flt){x, x, x, x};
}

static vec_flt vec_u32_reint_flt(vec_u32 x) {
    vec_flt r;
    memcpy(&r, &x, sizeof(x));
    return r;
}

static vec_u32 vec_flt_reint_u32(vec_flt x) {
    vec_u32 r;
    memcpy(&r, &x, sizeof(x));
    return r;
}

static vec_flt vec_flt_sq(vec_flt x) {
    return x * x;
}

static vec_flt vec_flt_abs(vec_flt x) {
    return vec_u32_reint_flt(vec_flt_reint_u32(x) & 0x7fffffff);
}

vec_flt vec_flt_cos(vec_flt x) {
    flt c[] = {
        0.999993295282167421664399661287022669f,
        -0.49991243971224581435251505760757806f,
        0.0414877480454292132253667471195955447f,
        -0.00127120948569655081466419067530634131f
    };
    x = vec_flt_abs(x);
    vec_u32 m = x > FLT_HPI;
    x = vec_flt_sq(
        vec_u32_reint_flt(
            m & vec_flt_reint_u32(FLT_PI - x) | ~m & vec_flt_reint_u32(x)
        )
    );
    return vec_u32_reint_flt(
        vec_flt_reint_u32(x * (x * (x * c[3] + c[2]) + c[1]) + c[0]) ^
        m & 0x80000000
    );
}

vec_flt vec_flt_sin(vec_flt x) {
    x -= FLT_HPI;
    return vec_flt_cos(
        x + vec_u32_reint_flt(
            x < -FLT_PI & vec_flt_reint_u32(vec_flt_fill(FLT_DPI))
        )
    );
}

enum {Z = 200000000};

static flt th(uns i) {
    return (flt)i * (FLT_DPI / (flt)(Z - 1)) - FLT_PI;
}

static void compute(vec_flt (*af)(vec_flt), vec_flt (*ef)(vec_flt), char *id) {
    static flt ap[Z], ex[Z];
    for (uns i = 0; i < Z; i += 4) {
        vec_flt x;
        for (uns j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            x[j] = th(i + j);
        }
        vec_flt r = af(x);
        memcpy(ap + i, &r, sizeof(r));
        r = ef(x);
        memcpy(ex + i, &r, sizeof(r));
    }
    dbl sum = 0.0;
    dbl max = 0.0;
    for (uns i = 0; i < Z; ++i) {
        dbl e = fabs((double)(ap[i] - ex[i]));
        sum += e;
        if (e > max) {
            max = e;
        }
    }
    printf("(%s) avg: %.12f max: %.12f\n", id, sum / (dbl)Z, max);
}

static vec_flt excos(vec_flt x) {
    return (vec_flt){
        (flt)cos((dbl)x[0]), (flt)cos((dbl)x[1]),
        (flt)cos((dbl)x[2]), (flt)cos((dbl)x[3])
    };
}

static vec_flt exsin(vec_flt x) {
    return (vec_flt){
        (flt)sin((dbl)x[0]), (flt)sin((dbl)x[1]),
        (flt)sin((dbl)x[2]), (flt)sin((dbl)x[3])
    };
}

int main() {
    compute(excos, vec_flt_cos, "vec_flt_cos");
    compute(exsin, vec_flt_sin, "vec_flt_sin");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks reasonable.  Being able to skip range-reduction by requiring limited-range input helps a lot, I'd imagine.

Comment: @PeterCordes Making an arbitrary input fit into the required range isn't *that* expensive (11 instructions, https://godbolt.org/z/EGbxdvs6f), but the main problem is that the error gets bigger as the initial input's absolute value gets bigger with the method I used. The error will remain if I subtract with a loop until it fits, but that's not efficient.

Comment: @PeterCordes BTW if you see the Godbolt link above, GCC uses `comiss` to branch while Clang chooses `cmpss` without a branch. The branching version won't make sense with the vectorized version, but in the given scalar code, which compiler is producing better code?

Comment: Yeah, range-reduction is a hard problem for accuracy.  To really do it well, you'd need extended-precision or something, e.g. for the value of Pi.  https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/ points out the problem for fsin as you approach sin(+Pi) ~= 0.0

Comment: branchless is great if the branch is unpredictable, otherwise branchy shortens the critical path and may run fewer total instructions.  Clang's implementation is a good branchless strategy, making good use of `cmpss` / `andps` it looks like.  Only briefly skimmed, though.